# using @AfterInsert with Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a @Entity class in a NestJs project.
I would like to use the @AfterInsert() listener to update some fields after the data was saved to the DB.
I can't use @BeforeInsert() as I need to have the newly created ID available.

bellow is my piece of code, but clearly the `qrcode` field isn't updated, remains blank

```
@Column({type: 'text', nullable: true})
    qrcode: string;

@AfterInsert()
 updateQrCode() {
        const code  = qrcode(this.id.toString());
        this.qrcode = code;
    }
```

This is the NestJS service triggering the DB insert

`

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private repo: Repository<User >,
    @InjectRepository(UserRole) private roleRepo: Repository<UserRole >,
    ) {}

    register(user: User){
        console.log('POST data:', user);
        const newUser = this.repo.create(user);
        return this.repo.save(newUser);
    }
```

`

How can I have the qrcode field updated automatically after the data was inserted?

Comment: which method have you called from typeorm's APIs? I guess not all of them triggers that after insert handler. Also, this is not related to nestjs at all, it is just typeorm stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can use typeorm Entity Subscribers like this:

```
...
import {
  EntitySubscriberInterface,
  EventSubscriber,
  InsertEvent,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Qrcode } from '../entities/qrcode.entity';

@EventSubscriber()
export class QrcodeSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Qrcode> {
  ...

  listenTo(): typeof Qrcode {
    return Qrcode;
  }

  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Qrcode>): Promise<void> {
    const { entity, manager } = event;
    if (!entity.qrcode) {
      entity.qrcode = qrcode(entity.id.toString());
      await manager.getRepository(Qrcode).save(entity);
    }
  }
}
```

And set subscribers in typeorm config:

```
...
subscribers: [__dirname + '/subscribers/QrcodeSubscriber{.ts,.js}']
```